# Do motherboards of the same form factor have the same ports in the same spots?

Tags: motherboard

The question is pretty much all in the title: in a compact case (already owned), will I be able to replace my old mATX motherboard with a shiny new mATX motherboard and have all the ports line up correctly with the slots on the back of the old case? I'm looking to replace my motherboard (and my CPU - I need a new motherboard for the CPU I'm wanting to buy) for as cheap as possible, and don't really want to have to buy a new case too.

[I hope this is the right forum to ask this question on. If it isn't, where should I go?]

Comment: Do you mean the ports in the back of the case?

Comment: @gronostaj yeah. I'll add that into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all motherboards in the ATX family have back ports in the same spot. Smaller form factor boards like mATX and µATX are still aligned to that spot.

Each motherboard has different port layout, but they come with a replaceable metal plate. You'll have to pry off the old one and put new one in before mounting the motherboard in the case.

As noted by @Jason, some manufacturers of pre-built systems use their custom components and don't follow standards. These PCs are generally hard to maintain using non-original parts and if you have one, then non-ATX case may  not be your only problem - for example the PSU may have proprietary connectors that won't fit ATX boards and standoffs may be located in non-standard locations, preventing you from securing the board in place properly.

Comment: This assumes they follow the ATX standard.  For example, [this Dell OptiPlex 3010](https://kbimg.dell.com/library/KB/DELL_ORGANIZATIONAL_GROUPS/DELL_GLOBAL/Content%20Team/Plex_3010_DT_rear.JPG) appears to be standard, but there is no "replaceable metal plate".

Comment: I think it is important to highlight the fact, while the I/O shield will be located in the same location, it can have the configuration the OEM desires.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem; the current motherboard I have definitely has a replaceable I/O sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Per the ATX specification:

> Toward the rear of the chassis, ATX defines a stacked I/O area that is 6.25" (158.75mm) wide by 1.75" (44.45mm) tall.  This area allows the use of stacked connectors on the motherboard to maximize the amount of I/O space available.
>
> A 0.1" (2.5 mm) keepout zone has been defined around the perimeter of the cutout area, on both the inside and outside surfaces of the chassis back panel.  **This required keepout zone provides a reserved space that can be used to clip a chassis independent I/O shield to the chassis back panel.**  No slots, tabs, notches, or other topographical features should be placed within the keepout zone.

In other words, the motherboard is supposed to come with an I/O shield that would clip into the chassis.  However, many computer manufacturers ignore the ATX specification and use proprietary cases and motherboards that don't allow standard components to be used.